# Html hidden input data is not passed in url

Tags: php

I used a hidden input field but its data is not shown in the url when I submit the form.

Here is the field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" >
```

And when I submit the form, its value is not shown in the url:

```
http://localhost/service/service.php?action=update_details&name='.kishor .'&lname='.patil .'&email='.kishor@gmail.com .'&username='.kishor123 .'&password='.1254.'&gender='.male.'&mobile='.9563201487 .'&address='.ads sd fds f.'id1='
```

I retrieve all form values through post using this code:

```
 $id = $_GET["edit_id"];
  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
         {

            $id1 = $_POST["id"];
            $name1=($_POST['name']);
            $lname1=($_POST['lname']);
            $email1=($_POST['email']);
            $username1=($_POST['username']);
            $password1=($_POST['password']);
            $mobile1=($_POST['mobile']);
            $address1=($_POST['address']);
            $gender1=($_POST['gender']);
          }
```

Comment: What's the value of <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" > ?

Comment: any interger which i got from other php file when i print it bellow get attribute it reflect it's value

Comment: You didnt give it a value. <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value=value>

Comment: no i didn't give it value

Comment: A field that does not have a value is not submitted.

Answer (score 3):

So what's the problem. You have create a input type which is hidden, no problem with that but you have not assign a value on it. Every input has to have a value. In your case you didn't assign a value on it.

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
```